# Please un-mark my question a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I recently asked the question at [1] which was marked as a duplicate. So I edited the question to explain explicitly how it is distinct from the linked question. No one has un-marked it as a duplicate yet.

Please either un-mark it as a duplicate or explain what additional information you need to see how it is distinct from the linked question.

As a new contributor to the ask Ubuntu community superfluous duplicate marking without explanation is a clear hindrance to participation in the community. It appears the ask Ubuntu community has had issues in the past with mods not actually reading and thinking about the questions they mark as duplicate. [2]

[1] [How do I install the debug symbols for gcov?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023644/how-do-i-install-the-debug-symbols-for-gcov)

[2] [Please read -and think- before you mark as a dupe](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15313/please-read-and-think-before-you-mark-as-a-dupe)

Comment: The reviewers on this site, not the mods are responsible for most dupe closures.  I don't know enough about debugging to cast a re-open vote, nor would I have casted a close vote for the same reason...

Comment: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://askubuntu.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: @dessert That's a good resource and it's good that it's linked to from here, especially for future readers. Note, however, that the OP already did what that advice recommends. I would consider posting on meta to be a quite reasonable approach here.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've reopened your question.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you're right that [your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023644/how-do-i-install-the-debug-symbols-for-gcov) wasn't a duplicate of the [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487222/how-to-install-debug-symbols-for-installed-packages), because you already enabled the repositories that provide "ddeb" debug symbol packages (the `-dbgsym` packages), and both answers to the linked question were just about doing that. **Fortunately, [Seth has reopened](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17859/22949) your question.**

#### Anyway, regarding the matter of *moderators* closing questions:

Your question has been [reopened by a moderator](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17859/22949), but no moderator was involved in *closing* it.

Although I do agree that moderators should be very careful when closing questions, as [Fabby mentioned](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17858/please-un-mark-my-question-a-duplicate#comment37459_17858) most questions are not closed by moderators. In fact, it is our ability as regular users to cast close and reopen votes that makes it possible for moderators to use a light touch and only use their very powerful close and reopen votes in cases that are especially uncontroversial or especially urgent or important. **Non-moderators with at least [3000 rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can vote to close and reopen questions.** Your question was closed by five regular (non-moderator) close votes.

[The other question you mentioned indirectly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758003/how-to-open-a-file-in-the-same-display-i-am-working-it) here, in that it was the subject of [the meta post you linked to](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15313/please-read-and-think-before-you-mark-as-a-dupe), was not really a case of *moderators* being overly quick to use their extra-powerful close votes, either. Although one of the users who voted to close that question *is* a moderator--and was one at the time--his close vote was no more powerful than anyone else's in that particular case, because [**it was the fifth close vote**](https://askubuntu.com/posts/758003/timeline#history_113b00f1-6104-407c-9b0e-1414eee2fb75). Four non-moderators had already voted to close the question (and their close votes were still in place, having not yet aged away).

None of this is to say that we don't wrongly close questions way more than ought to be considered acceptable. In fact, I even participated in [a clearly mistaken closure](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44154740#44154740) recently! (Sorry about that.) I'm not a moderator, though. **Most users who are [involved in "moderation" actions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) aren't.**